# Why is hibernate returning session is closed error

Tags: java, hibernate, session

The code below is returning a session is closed error. From my debugging, I know the session is open when this code is executed. In the debugging window `session.isOpen()` returns false, but at run time `session.isOpen()` throws a session is closed error. What's going on here...

```
    public static List<List<Object>> getProjectInfo(String projectName) {
    final List<List<Object>> list = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
    final String QUERY_STRING = HibernateUtil.getSqlFactory().getProperty("query")
    final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.doWork(new Work() {
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY_STRING);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            try {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    List<Object> ele = new ArrayList<Object>();
                    //do some processing here
                    //...
                    list.add(ele);
                }
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (HibernateException he) {
                logger.error(logger.getClass() + he.getMessage() + he.getStackTrace());
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
                throw he;
            } finally {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (session.isOpen()) {
                    session.close();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it looks like I had an extra transaction commit in there somewhere. woops!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow your code in the following format.

```
Session session = null;
Transaction tx = null;

try{
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    tx.setTimeout(5);

    //doSomething(session);

    tx.commit();


}catch(RuntimeException e){
    try{
        tx.rollback();
    }catch(RuntimeException rbe){
        log.error("Couldn’t roll back transaction", rbe);
    }
    throw e;
}finally{
    if(session!=null){
        session.close();
    }
}
```

In Hibernate, the transaction management is quite standard, just remember any exceptions thrown by Hibernate are FATAL, you have to roll back the transaction and close the current session immediately.

### Resource Link:

1. [Hibernate Transaction handle example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-transaction-handle-example/)